# Can't call the window position object in a function

Tags: javascript, object, position

I have the following function that works like a champ:

```
//To find the position of an element
    function getPosition(el) {
  var xPos = 0;
  var yPos = 0;

  while (el) {
    if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
      // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
      var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
    } else {
      // for all other non-BODY elements
      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    }

    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
  };
}
```

so when I call the getPosition I get the numbers as an object like that:

```
>{x: 200, y: 500}
```

Now I have another function that I am building to trigger an event with a certain position, but I can't call the getPosition number right... I have tried dozens of variations, certainly I am missing something here.
Below is a simple function to show the way I am calling the position number is not correct:

```
function test () {
  console.log(getPosition(img));//An image - getPosition identify it to be at {x:200,y:500}
  if (getPosition(img) == (200,500)){ 
    console.log('It is there!')
  } else {
    console.log('it is not there!')
  }
};
```

I have also tried between other options this:

```
function test () {
  console.log(getPosition(img));
  var x = 200;
  var y = 500;
  if (getPosition(img) == {x,y}){ 
    console.log('It is there!')
  } else {
    console.log('it is not there!')
  }
};
```

and this:

```
function test () {
  console.log(getPosition(img));
  if (getPosition(img) == {x: 200,y: 500}){ 
    console.log('It is there!')
  } else {
    console.log('it is not there!')
  }
};
```

So I only get 'it is not there!', I have tried many different ways to find a way to compare without success.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Much appreciated.

Comment: You can try printing the values you are getting after calling the function, insert `debugger` at the start of `getPosition` and see how things are going for the `img`.

Curious why you are not using `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the ideas. I was printing the values along the way, but I got stuck when trying to use them, they seemed similar, but obviously not undestood as same. The solution below game me the right way to get it sorted. Regarding the 'getBounding', I am not familiar with the option suggested, which gives me the opportunity to learn. I will have a look for the alternatives using it. Thank you very much for taking the time. All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getPosition()` function returns an Object. So you must check that objects `x` and `y` properties to make sure they match what you want.

The easiest way is to just check both x and y individually in the `if` statement. This seems to be what you were trying to do, but you just had the syntax a bit off by trying to check the x and y properties all in 1 statement.

```js
//To find the position of an element
function getPosition(el) {
  var xPos = 0;
  var yPos = 0;

  while (el) {
    if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
      // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
      var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
    } else {
      // for all other non-BODY elements
      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    }

    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
  };
}

test()

function test() {
  var img = document.getElementById("the-image");
  
  console.log(getPosition(img));
  
  var imageLocation = getPosition(img);
  
  if (imageLocation.x === 8 && imageLocation.y === 22) {
    console.log('It is there!')
  } else {
    console.log('it is not there!')
  }
};
```

```html
<img id="the-image" src=""/>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew,Much appreciated

Comment: It worked nicely ! Thank you very much for showing the way! I now understood my blunder and the fact that calling x and y separately would be the way. Much appreciated and Merry Christmas.

Comment: @Endeavorwebs glad to help! feel free to accept it as the answer that most helped you.

Comment: Sure! Just done it, I missed this stage. Much appreciated!